# could not autowire sessionFactory

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, postgresql

I can't autowire sessionFactory bean defined in context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:8080/come_to_blog_db</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.password">admin</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.lime.model.User</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

maybe other cfg files can be helpful, web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">


    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>web-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>web-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/web-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.lime" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

what can be wrong? i have all 3 files in the same directory, thanks for advices.
EDIT: stack trace: http://pastebin.com/tY87DgLb

Comment: What does `I can't autowire` mean _exactly_. Provide errors and stacktraces.

Comment: Please show your code where you autowiering the sessionfactory and the stacktrace you got.

Comment: here is stack trace: http://pastebin.com/tY87DgLb

Answer (score 0):

Since your servlet is named `web-dispatcher` and your servlet xml file is `web-dispatcher-servlet.xml`, you don't need to specify it in `configLocation`, Spring will find it in classpath using `[servletName]-servlet.xml`. But you need to specify `context.xml`, which Spring needs to know about(in order to configure sessionFactory bean, and other beans).

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: i already added listener and updated session-factory.xml to context.xml, but i don't have other beans yet.

Comment: i updated my post, but i have a question, what should i import into contextConfigLocation (in context-param tags), dispetcher or context???

Comment: Because Spring `ContextLoaderListener` needs to know about your xml context file. I updated my post

Comment: thanks, it seems to be solved, but I'm getting another errors :/, warning, severe from maven, and then exception, i spent 2 days configuring webapp but i still cant connect my database :/ http://pastebin.com/pPxzbpiE

Comment: Jesus Christ cmon and kill me, i didn't notice i was writing bad connection.url, i was typing 8080 instead of 5432, awwwrh.. but could you please check my another problem? it seems I'm finally connected with my database, but: org.hibernate.HibernateException: createSQLQuery is not valid without active transaction

Comment: You need to configure `TransactionManager`, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739791/spring-no-transaction-manager-has-been-configured
Or file another question in stackoverflow.com.